# Customizing Work Item Types to behave like User Stories in the Agile process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am currently using devops (cloud) services. I have created a custom Work Item Type (WIT) within an inherited process from Agile. I would like to configure it to behave like exactly like Agile's User Story WIT.  By this I mean:

1. The WIT should be addable in the taskboard view of the Sprints (see first pic, **WorkItemTaskBoard**).
2. One should be able to add tasks to the item just like User Story's.
3. The WIT should rank below features in the WIT hierarchy. This way when it is added as a child of a feature it will be visible in the Backlogs view (see second pic, **BacklogChildMissing**)

According to my reading I need to export my inherited process as an XML, edit said XML then import the modified XML. I have two issues with this.

A.  I have not found any reliable documentation how to perform the above.

B.  Although I am using cloud based Devops (dev.azure.com) and am the organization owner I do not appear to have rights to import a process (see third pic, **ImportProcessMissing**)

Can anyone confirm that I need to perform the export, edit, import the XML as specified above in order to achieve 1, 2 and 3? If so, I would need help in figuring out how to import the process.

**WorkItemTaskBoard**

[image: WorkItemTaskBoard]

**BacklogChildMissing**  - The WIT is not displayed despite being a child of Test Feature.

[image: BacklogChildMissing]

**ImportProcessMissing**  - Import button is missing.

[image: ImportProcessMissing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps like as below image shows to configure the customer WIT in the inherited Agile process.

- Create the custom WIT.
- Set the custom WIT as the **`Stories`** backlog level.

[image]

After above settings, in the project which is using the inherited Agile process, you can manage the custom WIT like as **`User Story`**.

See below example:

[image]

Comment: This was really spot on.  I looked at the backlog levels view that you screenshotted extensively before posting here;  due to the confusing UI, was convinced that "Stories" could only refer to User Stories.